# Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "alias:/path" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-5

I am creating a new react app and trying to configure webpack compiler from scratch.
The issue happens when running the build command with `webpack -c config/webpack.config.ts` - It gives an error as following;

```
ERROR in containers:/App
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "containers:/App" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "containers:" URIs.
    at /home/myuser/dev/projects/tsxpress-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:659:26
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/myuser/dev/projects/tsxpress-boilerplate/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/home/myuser/dev/projects/tsxpress-boilerplate/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at Object.processResource (/home/myuser/dev/projects/tsxpress-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:656:9)
    at processResource (/home/myuser/dev/projects/tsxpress-boilerplate/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:220:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/myuser/dev/projects/tsxpress-boilerplate/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:171:10)
    at runLoaders (/home/myuser/dev/projects/tsxpress-boilerplate/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:397:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/home/myuser/dev/projects/tsxpress-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:646:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/home/myuser/dev/projects/tsxpress-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:791:15)
    at /home/myuser/dev/projects/tsxpress-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1239:12
 @ ./client/app/index.tsx 12:28-54
```

Any idea what might have caused this or what I am missing? Any suggestion is appreciated.

---

My directory structure is as following:

```
node_modules/
client/
  public/
  app/
    assets/
    index.tsx
server/
shared/
  http/
  models/
  state/
  utils/
build/
config/
  webpack.config.js
```

File `index.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { store } from 'shared:/states/store';
import App from 'containers:/App';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

File `tsconfig.json/compilerOptions/paths`

```
  "paths": {
    "shared:/*": ["shared/*"],
    "containers:/*": ["client/app/views/containers/*"],
  }
```

File `webpack.config.js`;

```
resolve: {
  modules: paths.clientAppModules,
  extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  alias: {
    'shared:': '/home/myuser/dev/projects/tsxpress-boilerplate/shared',
    'containers:': '/home/myuser/dev/projects/tsxpress-boilerplate/client/app/views/containers'
  }
},
```

Dependencies:

- "typescript": "^4.1.5",
- "webpack": "^5.23.0",
- "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"

Please let me know you need more details;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is also experiencing the same issue, I have raised this here [webpack github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12792)

Apparently, this is a new feature introduced in webpack 5 that would recognize all `prefix:` as a part of URL - Thus the error.

I fixed this by renaming my aliases from `containers:/` to `containers-/` - And it now works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Look here https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/11095/files

https://github.com/vankop/webpack/blob/7bbc2aa3ceb34d93b6f17549f02eca3518d680d2/lib/index.js#L433

https://github.com/vankop/webpack/blob/7bbc2aa3ceb34d93b6f17549f02eca3518d680d2/lib/schemes/FileUriPlugin.js#L25

What you are missing is that schemes other than "http" or "file" aren't supported by webpack. The error message is saying that.

```
import { store } from 'shared:/states/store';
import App from 'containers:/App';
```

`shared` and `containers` are not supported schemes, webpack won't pass them forward to babel/typescript, so this kind of URI won't work.

Unless, you are willing to write a bypass plugin, I though someone would've already made one, I only found this error.
It seems kind of easy to copy the file plugin and add more schemes, that's what I'm going to do.

[edit:] In Webpack5, you can for example:

Just do this.

```js
"use strict";

const node_url = require("url");

class AnySchemeUriPlugin {

    constructor(options = {}) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(
            "AnySchemeUriPlugin",
            (compilation, { normalModuleFactory }) => {
                Array.from(this.options.schemes).forEach(scheme => {
                    normalModuleFactory.hooks.resolveForScheme
                        .for(scheme)
                        .tap("AnySchemeUriPlugin", resourceData => {
                            const uri = resourceData.resource.replace(`${scheme}://`, 'file://');
                            const url = new node_url.URL(uri);
                            const path = node_url.fileURLToPath(url);
                            const query = url.search;
                            const fragment = url.hash;
                            resourceData.path = path;
                            resourceData.query = query;
                            resourceData.fragment = fragment;
                            resourceData.resource = path + query + fragment;
                            return true;
                        });
                });
            }
        );
    }
}

module.exports = AnySchemeUriPlugin;
```

then, in your `webpack.config`

```js
    // The HtmlWebpackPlugin allows us to use a template for the index.html page
    // and automatically injects <script> or <link> tags for generated bundles.
    const commonPlugins = [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: baseConfig.indexHtmlTemplate,
            inlineSource: '^.+\.(css)$',
        }),
        new AnySchemeUriPlugin({
            schemes: ['ssr']
        })
        //new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    ];

    return {
        entry: {
            app: [
                baseConfig.fsharpEntry
            ],
        },
        context: baseConfig.srcDir,
        plugins: isProduction
            ? commonPlugins.concat([
            ]) : commonPlugins,
     }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help and sorry for the late response. I have tried creating this custom plugin and implements it in my webpack configuration as per you stated. However, the error still persists.

Even though I was wondering why we needed this extra plugin, as per my understanding, webpack should've supported this based on `alias` configuration. I am trying to crawl into CRA and see if I can spot anything.